# Bitand na clausula where

Tags: pl-sql, oracle10g

Preciso fazer a seguinte Query, porém está gerando alguns erros de sintaxe ou lógica.

```
SELECT campo_X, campo_Y
FROM tabela_Z
WHERE( 
        ( 
           BITAND(1, 1) > 0 AND campo_A  NOT IN (2,4,8,9)
        )
        OR
        (
           BITAND(2, 2) > 0 
           AND campo_A NOT IN (2,4,8,9)
           AND campo_B = 1
        )
        -- Mais bitand's ...
      );
```

Terei que implementar mais blocos de `bitand` dentro da cláusula `where`, cada bit faz algo diferente.

O erro aparece na condição do `bitand > 0` quando executo todo select, porém quando executo só um do bloco, ou seja, comento um e deixo o outro ele executa e traz as informações, mas quando executo os dois blocos junto gera o erro.

Se alguém tiver uma outra solução, pensei em um `CASE` ou `IF`, mas aparentemente o `IF` não aceitável dentro da clausula `Where`.

Comment: Qual a razão do uso do BITAND ?!

Comment: Esse Select será implementado em uma SP que utiliza um mapa de Bits, por isso o BITAND, o primeiro valor da função BITAND será informada através de parâmetro do tipo INTEIRO. Então pode ser que vários bits esteja ligado ao mesmo tempo ou apenas um deles, sendo assim para cada 1 ligado deverá realizar uma condição para dados diferentes.

Comment: Não conheço a function a fundo mas pelo que entendi ela retorna a quantidade de bits concidentes entre dois inteiros positivos e , pelo que entendi , se quer comparar bit a bit , creio que ela não seria útil.

Comment: @Motta a questão em si não seria a comparação, quanto a utilização da Function está tranquilo ela atende, a questão eh que preciso que ela funcione ai dentro da clausula Where. Já consegui fazer isso, mas tem um problema. Por exemplo, da forma que aparece o trecho de código que coloquei aqui, o Bit 0 e Bit 1 estaria ligados, então teria que trazer o resultado da condição do bit 0, mais o resultado da condição do bit 1. Motta tu conhece alguma outra logica para eu fazer isso, atualmente uso concatenação de Strings com Union, mas meu chefe quer otimizar a SP.

Comment: Tentou trazer o valor em binário como string (não sei se tem function para isto) a comparação seria char a char da direita para esquerda.

Comment: Bitand funciona muito bem, problema na clausula Where, cada bit vai um where diferente do jeito que esta ai funciona, só que se dois ou mais bits estiverem ligados ele só mostrar o resultado do primeiro bit que ele encontrar ligado no fluxo da execução, mas eu preciso que ele execute os outros também caso esteja ligado, pode estar todos ligado, por exemplo se eu passar como argumento o inteiro 255 para o primeiro parâmetro da function todos os bits estariam ligados, então ele teria que executar todos os blocos dentro do where. Preciso de uma solução para resolver essa questão. IF não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

A solução ficou assim:

```
SELECT z.campo_X, z.campo_Y, h.campo_H
FROM tabela_Z z
LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela_H h
ON z.campo_Z_COD = h.campo_H_COD
WHERE( 
      ( 
        BITAND(1, 1) > 0 
        AND z.campo_A  NOT IN (2,4,8,9)
      )
      OR
      (
        BITAND(2, 2) > 0 
        AND z.campo_A NOT IN (2,4,8,9)
        AND z.campo_B = 1
      )
      OR
      (
        BITAND(4, 4) > 0 
        AND z.campo_A NOT IN (2,4,8,9)
        AND z.campo_B = 2
        AND h.campo_H = 4258
      )
      -- aqui mais blocos até o bit 7, de 0 a 7, 8 Bits.
  );
```

O Bitand checa bit a bit se um esta ligado ou não, se tiver ligado retorna interio maior zero, quando desligado retorna 0.